# Curl request to IPFS Get API adds bytes to header of downloaded file

Tags: curl, python-requests, ipfs

I have an IPFS node on an linux box. If i use:

```
ipfs get QmYqGwoiuw47cLhrtQ5yg1TnS6n2ekcLSZZt35gGestTuo
```

at command line the ipfs image (a png) is downloaded and usable.

However when i hit the equivalent endpoint using CURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/get?arg=QmYqGwoiuw47cLhrtQ5yg1TnS6n2ekcLSZZt35gGestTuo' --output QmYqGwoiuw47cLhrtQ5yg1TnS6n2ekcLSZZt35gGestTuo
```

The file downloaded is identical except it has some bytes at the start of the file.

[image]

These appear before the �PNG identifier at the top of the file. (Appears to be the CID followed by some nullstrings then some numbers)

Is there anything i'm doing wrong in my post request to download the file correctly? As currently the files downloaded using CURL are unusable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#api-v0-get) is used to get IPFS objects:

> ### /api/v0/get
>
> Download IPFS objects.

What you likely want is [cat](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#api-v0-cat):

> ### /api/v0/cat
>
> Show IPFS object data.

Example:

```bash
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/cat?arg=QmYqGwoiuw47cLhrtQ5yg1TnS6n2ekcLSZZt35gGestTuo' --output QmYqGwoiuw47cLhrtQ5yg1TnS6n2ekcLSZZt35gGestTuo
```

Header of output:

[image: PNG header]